# Sending email from inside of a docker container fails with error in name resolution

Tags: docker, email, smtplib

I am trying to send an email from an ubuntu-based docker container. Ultimately, I want to send emails inside of a Flask application, using the following code snippet:

```py
import smtplib
def send_email(from_addr="senderaddress@companyname.com", to_addrs="receiveraddress@companyname.com",
               msg="\ntest Email"):
    mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('mail.companyname.com', 25)
    mailserver.ehlo()
    mailserver.starttls()
    mailserver.sendmail(from_addr, to_addrs, msg)
    mailserver.quit()

send_email()
```

When I run it, I get the following Python error on creation of the `smptlib.SMTP` server object:

> email socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

Sending the email using the same script outside of the docker container works (Windows host system). What may be a good way to fix this (note that the SMTP server intended for use is not running on localhost)?
Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a published email, it means inside the docker it cannot resolve the domain IP address. There are several reasons for this problem to solve, Firewalls, IP tables, docker network, and so on.

For first try, you can add you dns, to the docker-compose file to see if it can resolve the domain.

If it did not resolve the domain, means there is a problem between your docker and dns server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you be more specific on the part of 'adding DNS to the docker-compose file'?

Comment: For example if you use  8.8.8.8 as your dns, add this line to your docker-compose file.

dns:
  - "8.8.8.8"